# Hosts aren't accessible by name in docker compose on Windows

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose

I have two, windows-based images that I'm using with docker compose.

The `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
services:
  application:
    image: myapp-win:latest
    container_name: "my-app"
    # for diagnosis
    entrypoint: ["cmd"]
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    # /diagnosis
    env_file: .myapp/.env
    environment:
        - POSTGRES_URI=jdbc:postgresql://db0:5432/mydatabase
    depends_on:
        db0:
            condition: service_healthy

  db0:
    image: stellirin/postgres-windows:10.10
    container_name: "my-db"
    ports:
        - 10000:5432 # this doesn't seem to work in windows
    env_file:
        - .postgres/.env
    volumes:
        - .postgres\initdb\:c:\docker-entrypoint-initdb.d\
    healthcheck:
        test: [ "CMD", "pg_isready", "-q", "-d", "${POSTGRES_DATABASE}", "-U", "${POSTGRES_USER}" ]
        timeout: 45s
        interval: 10s
        retries: 10
    restart: unless-stopped
```

With the two containers started, I accessed the terminal for the `my-db` container and got its IP address.

Next, I accessed the terminal for the `my-app` container.  I was able to ping the `my-db` container by its IP address.  However, it did not respond by its hostname:

```
c:\app> ping db0
Ping request could not find host db0.
```

This is symptommatic why the application can't reach the database using the `POSTGRES_URI` variable.

Is there a different syntax for the hostname in a Windows container?

** edit **

I'm not able to ping outside the network, from either container:

```
c:\app> ping 8.8.8.8
Request timed out.
```

Not sure if this is relevant.

Comment: just `ping` specifically may be blocked somewhere, try `curl` or similar to reach an address - however, it seems more likely that your network configuration really is unhappy .. what host operating system are you using?

Comment: Windows 10 enterprise

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of container OS, to my knowledge, referring to the other name (`db0`) directly won't directly work *inside* the container, but is simply exposed to the other compose entries

Instead, set an env var dependent on the name and read it in the container

```yaml
    environment:
      - "ADDRESS_DB=db0"
```

Then, if you want to be able to `ping db0` or similar, have a script set the env var as an available host name on start

Alternatively, you may have success setting it the `extra_hosts` field, but I haven't tested this and you may need to give it a different name to prevent interpolation

```yaml
    extra_hosts:
      - db_url:db0
```

Comment: I need the `POSTGRES_URI` variable to contain the correct hostname or IP address.

Comment: what does it contain if you just display it in the container?

Comment: `jdbc:postgresql://db0:5432/mydatabase`.  The problem is the hostname.  This syntax works correctly with a Linux (WSL2 to be precise), but not with Windows.